# Check if there is enough available memory for a docker container

Tags: docker

I am using the create container api to start some containers.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ContainerCreate

Is there any way to check with the API what the current usage of the memory is, to decide if can create the container or if it should wait?

1. Look at current running containers and their memory usage
2. Look at current running containers and check for how much asked memory.

Benefits of 1 would be that it can check current live memory usage, but would mean i have to monitor the usage in real time.

Benefits of 2 would be that I set the memory limit for each container created, and sum these values to check if there is room for the next.

Whats possible. What do other orchestrates do?

Comment: Kubernetes keeps track of this outside of Docker, I believe.